# Camera on mkr1000 or nodemcu 0.9

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu, mkr1000

My question is: it is possible to connect camera on an Arduino/Genuino [mkr1000](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-mkr1000) or to a [NodeMCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NodeMCU) 0.9?

If yes which one?

As far as I now [ArduCam](http://www.arducam.com/arducam-supports-esp8266-arduino-board-wifi-websocket-camera-demo/#more-1093) OV2640 has ported a library for ESP8266 (that is the chip inside the nodemcu)? Where can I find it and how does I plug the camera to the board?

Reading the camera user guide I've found that:

> The ArduCAM mini can be used in any platforms like Arduino, [...] as long as they have SPI and I2C interface

Does one of these 2 board have both [SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus) and [I2C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) interfaces

EDIT: Here I list my personal search with possible interesting results:

- Here is a [guide of arducam on ESP8266 module ESP-12E](https://cdn.instructables.com/ORIG/F9W/40DH/ILJSHKZK/F9W40DHILJSHKZK.pdf) (My nodemcu is ESP-12)
- Here [another guide for ESP8266-12E](http://www.instructables.com/id/ArduCAM-Mini-ESP8266-Web-Camera/)

I hope that can be useful the wiring scheme to ESP8266-12E

```
     ArduCAM mini   ->    ESP8266-12E
         CS         ->        D0
        MOSI        ->        D7
        MISC        ->        D6
         SCK        ->        D5
         GND        ->       GND
         VCC        ->       3V3
         SDA        ->        D2
         SCL        ->        D1
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Because you didn't do any research yourself. The linked MKR1000 site mentions it and figuring it out for the NodeMCU isn't hard either.

Comment: @gre_gor I've added also other research. I asked only if it was possible on my board. Everywhere I find only sketches and examples for ESP8266-12E. I cannot be sure if it works or not so I am asking here. 
The question was if any cam is working there, my idea was the arducam that I linked. I make the question because it seems possible that the cam works but I've no certainty.
Sorry if I don't know what are those 2 interfaces but from wikipedia I don't understand much.
Tell me what do you want from me to prove that I made researches, I've linked all the stuff that can be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of levels of names in your question, so here are how they fit together:

**ESP8266** - This is the bare chip found in the wide range of "esp8266"-based boards/modules/etc. The chip itself has no flash storage, no clock/oscillator, and no voltage regulation.

The I/O pins on the ESP8266 bare chip have labels like `GPIO0`, `GPIO1`, etc.

[image: Chip outlined in Red is the ESP8266]

Chip outlined in Red is the ESP8266 alone.

So, to be of much use, the chips are often found on other modules along with flash memory, an oscillator, perhaps voltage regulation, a PCB antenna for the wifi portion, etc.

A popular "brand" of such module is the **[AI-Thinker](https://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=esp8266-module-family)** modules, with names like

1. ESP-01
2. ESP-07
3. ESP-12
4. ESP-12E
5. ESP-12F

The different modules have different PCB sizes, but most notably, different numbers of pins from the actual ESP8266 chip brought out to the module's pins.

These often also call the I/O pins names like `GPIO0`, `GPIO1`, etc.

[image]

These ESP-xx modules, in turn, are often incorporated into larger modules that then add a USB-serial chip, LEDs, etc. One popular line are the [NodeMCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NodeMCU) series.

These modules provide different names for the I/O pins. **NodeMCU** in particular uses `D0`, `D1`, etc. and these don't correspond to the same numeric suffix as the bare chip. [This chart](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/gpio/) gives the mappings for NodeMCU modules.

[image]

**ANSWER**

Thus, in the [web page you linked about the ArduCAM and ESP8266](http://www.arducam.com/arducam-supports-esp8266-arduino-board-wifi-websocket-camera-demo/#more-1093), you can see a chart on the Hardware Connection of the the ArduCAM pins, and equivalent pins for both the NodeMCU-style pin names, and also the AI-Thinker and bare chip pin names.

The ESP-12 and ESP-12E both have the exact same ESP8266 chip inside, and the same amount of flash memory. There is no difference between them as far as connecting to the ArduCAM is concerned. The ESP-12E has a few more pins brought out to the headers than the ESP-12.

So, as long as you have D0, D1, D2, D5, D6, and D7 on a NodeMCU, **OR** GPIO4, GPIO5, GPIO12, GPIO13, GPIO14, and GPIO16 on the AI-Thinker module, then you can hook up the ArduCAM, as these are all the pins described in the hookup table.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the answer. This is far better than what I expected!